# Disk I/O and load average peaks once every hour

Tags: debian, php, disk-usage, nginx, load-average

We have updated our server from Debian Wheezy to Jessie and from php5.6 to php7.0, but now we have a disk I/O and load average peak exactly every hour. The exact time depends on the system start time.

On this server, we have:

- nginx/1.10.1
- PHP 7.0.8-1~dotdeb+8.1
- Percona mysql server 5.6.30-76.3-log
- dovecot 2.2.devel
- postfix 2.11.3-1
- java 1.7.0_101

We have tried to return to php5.6, disable cron, disable postfix and dovecot, stop our Java app, but nothing helped.

The peaks look like the following:
[image]

The iotop looks like the following:
[image]

How can I know exactly what causes these peaks and eliminate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/ which have done cache clean every hour.

Configuration it to store files on tmpfs fixed the problem.